# Prove that any subfield of $\Bbb R$ contains $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Prove that any subfield of $\Bbb R$ must contain $\Bbb Q$.

Now for any subfield $F$ of $\Bbb R$, $1\in F$ so, $\Bbb Z \subset F \Rightarrow \Bbb Q \subseteq F$. Have I done it correctly?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Depending on how technical you want your proof to be, you could prove those steps using induction.

Comment: In priciple Yes, though you may want to elaborate by which method one can conclude from  $1\in F$ that $\mathbb Z\subseteq F$ and by which method one can conclude from this that $\mathbb Q\subseteq F$. (as in: Why is your proof better than "$1\in F$, hence $\mathbb Q\subseteq F$"?)

Comment: Your proof is correct, but could perhaps use some more details (why do you reach each conclusion?)

Also, why doesn't your proof work for $\mathbb Z/p$? You must be using some property of $\mathbb R$, but you don't explicitly say what property you are using.

Comment: The first thing is trivial as $F$ is a field and second one comes from the property of rings of fraction.

Comment: @user152715 "trivial as F is a field" That reasoning is insufficient. You cannot conclude that $\Bbb Z$ is contained in a field "because F is a field and has 1." A finite field provides a counterexample. The right thing to justify us that every field of characteristic 0 has a copy of $\Bbb Z$ and then also a copy of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: So how can I write clearly that $\Bbb R$ has no subfield of charecteristic finite. I can see it but give me some solid logic. rschwieb

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  I would add some words explaining why each implication is true, along the lines that $n \in F$ because you can add $n\ 1$'s together, then $-n \in F$ because you can form $0-n$, then $n/m \in F$ because you can divide.

I think most would go the other direction by saying given any $q \in \Bbb Q$, express it as $m/n$, then $m,n \in F$ because...